# Need a weighted scoring algorithm to combine scores with different scale

Tags: algorithm

I am working on a scoring system for tickets and each ticket can potentially have up to 4 kinds of different scores. What I would like to do is to combine these four scores in the a final score and prioritize the tickets. I'd also like to assign a weight to each of the 4 score. The details of the 4 scores are listed below:

Score A:  1-5 scale, desired relative weight: 2

Score B:  1-4 scale, desired relative weight: 3

Score C:  1-10 scale, desired relative weight: 2

Score D:  1-5 scale, desired relative weight: 1

Some requirements:

(1) Each ticket may come with arbitrary number of scores, so sometimes we have all 4, sometimes we have no scores(Default final score needed).

(2) If the ticket gets a high score from multiple sources, the final score should be even higher, vice versa.

(3) The score with higher weight plays a bigger role in deciding the final score

(4) The final score should be in 1-4 scale.

I wonder if there are any existing algorithm for solving this kind of issue? Thanks ahead.

Desired input and output example:

```
(1) Input:   {A:N/A, B:4, C:9, D:N/A}
Output:  {Final: 4}
```

Since for both score it's a high score

```
(2) Input:   {A:3, B:N\A, C:8, D:1}
Output:  {Final:3}
```

Although score D is small, it has small weight, so still we get a relative big final score.

```
(3) Input:   {A:N\A, B:N\A, C:N\A, D:N\A}
Output:  {Final:2}
```

Arguable default score.

The overall idea is to rank the tickets according to the four scores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Define a initial relative weight `W` for every score.**

**Convert every initial score `S` from it's initial scale `A` into a universal score `S'` on a universal scale `B` from minB to maxB.**

[image: <code>S'=(S-minA)/(maxA-minA)*(maxB-minB)+minB</code>]

If a score is missing give it a default value for example

[image: http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cinline%20%5Chuge%20RankingScore%3D%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5En%5Cleft%20%28%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%5Ba%5D%7BS_i%5Ea%20+%5Csum_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5En%20%5Cleft%20%28S_j%5Ea%5Cright%20%29%7D%7D%7Bn+1%7D*%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%5Bb%5D%7BW_i%5Eb+%5Csum_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5En%20%5Cleft%20%28W_j%5Eb%5Cright%20%29%7D%7D%7Bn+1%7D%20%5Cright%20%29]

**Calculate the final score with your new S**

[image: http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cinline%20%5Chuge%20RankingScore%3D%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5En%5Cleft%20%28%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%5Ba%5D%7BS_i%5Ea%20+%5Csum_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5En%20%5Cleft%20%28S_j%5Ea%5Cright%20%29%7D%7D%7Bn+1%7D*%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%5Bb%5D%7BW_i%5Eb+%5Csum_%7Bj%3D1%7D%5En%20%5Cleft%20%28W_j%5Eb%5Cright%20%29%7D%7D%7Bn+1%7D%20%5Cright%20%29]

a and b are your weights for the score and the weight.

If you make a large, then only really the biggest score will play a value, if you make b large, then only really the biggest weight will play a value.

Having a and b between [1;2] shouldn't be too extreme. With a or b being 1 you will have a normal weighting system, that doesn't weight bigger scores more.

Comment: Hey, found this answer extremely helpful. But could you please provide some intuition behind why this works? Much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hey, is there any update on this ? Any intuitive explanation regarding this ?

Comment: This basically consists of 3 parts. Not 100% sure which one you're interested in. The sum at the bottom is using the algebra for the sum which says for a = infinite -> term = max(S_i). Basically you know that x^n grows faster than x, so if you do that  before summing and then take the root, you'll have bigger initial numbers have bigger impact on the sum.

Comment: But tbh. the question is very specific, and the answer aswell. I have to reread it every time. If you have a more general or specific question, feel free to ask it directly, maybe link this question, and say you want a similiar algorithm.